# Tab+swipe Gesture, Custom grid view, Fragments

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-custom-view, swipe-gesture

[image: This is my app snapshot]

Well I have this app with swipe gesture functionality between fragments which they contains images which are located in the resources folders .. but when i swipe left and right I noticed that the performance is bad and slow .. Any suggestions to improve it?

And here is the header of the main activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Roman Curtain", "Roller Blinds", "Wooden Blinds" ,"Kitchen Blinds"};
//  
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
```

and here is tab pager adapter :

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new RomanCurtains();
        case 1:
            return new RollerBlinds();
        case 2:
            return new WoodenBlinds();
        case 3:
            return new KitchenBlinds();
//      case 4:
//          return new KitchenBlinds();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a two reason for the bad performance

1. Your images are too big and takes too much space in the memory
   You can put the images in `assets` folder and then use `Picasso` library to use them. It will improve the performance. 
   https://github.com/square/picasso
2. All the pages in the `ViewPager` is in the memory if you use `PagerAdapter` or `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
   If you use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` only the visible page and the
   pages adjacent to that page are kept in the memory. This will
   improve the performance too.

Comment: i am working on it .. but the thing is it contains tabs on an action bar . can i do it with FragmentStatePagerAdapter ?

Comment: ActionBar tabs is not important at all. You should use ViewPager. ActionBar tabs is just a connection to navigate. Are you using a PagerAdapter for your ViewPager? Can you post the code for it?

Comment: yes i can .. i will edit the code now.. but i need the action bar too it's necessary in my app @tasomaniac

Comment: Just change FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter it will improve the performance little bit. If the images are too big, try Picasso as well.

Comment: i tried to install Picasso library but it keep show me an errors

Comment: Installing it is very easy. If you use Eclipse just put the JAR file into libs folder. You do not need to do anything.

Comment: i know but i don't know how to link it to my grid view ,, do you have any tutorials to help me out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50130/discussion-between-tasomaniac-and-sereen-shalby)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)